# CanonSDK with OpenFrameworks and OfxCanon

Tags: codeblocks, openframeworks

I'm trying to pull video from a **600D** into **OpenFrameworks** using the **ofxCanon** add-on in Windows and **CodeBlocks**. I've followed the instructions here:

http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/ofxcanon-installation-on-windows/11173

But when I go to compile a test I get lots (50) of the following error on various lines:

```
..\..\..\..\..\..\EDSDKv2130W\Windows\EDSDK\Header\EDSDKTypes.h 172 error: 'EdsUInt32' does not name a type
```

I'm using **Windows 8**. Any ideas appreciated!